# Error installing opencv-python specific version

Tags: python, opencv, pip

Because I had

> **recursion is detected during loading of "cv2" binary extensions**

issue, I tried

> pip install opencv-python==4.5.3.56

to be installed. However; I am suffering

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such
> file or directory:
> 'C:\Users\shim.DESKTOP-JDBQQEL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0ff44i7d\opencv-python_c8960a5df32f42f599355ae0c4f06897\opencv/samples/winrt_universal/VideoCaptureXAML/video_capture_xaml/video_capture_xaml.WindowsPhone/video_capture_xaml.WindowsPhone.vcxproj.filters'

problem. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: the pathname of the folder looks odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that the character length of your path is more than 260 characters and Windows does not support more than this character.
I suggest you remove your Windows limitation from this link or similar solutions.
[[url]](https://www.howtogeek.com/266621/how-to-make-windows-10-accept-file-paths-over-260-characters/)